# Limit Database Size for a particular Package on VPS with cPanel

Tags: mysql, database, vps

Is it possible to limit mySQL database size for a particular package (created via whm)? So we can offer a kind of trial hosting account. Trial should obviously have catches or we won't really earn. I have seen companies using that trick.

Answer (score 1):

MySQL doesn't have native support for quotas. You could use conventional file system quotas and `chown` the respective DB files in `/var/lib/mysql`.

Or you could write a trigger that does some calc on the fly, but either way, its a good road to DB corruption.